# How to make a filename by date with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to Powershell and would like to output the result of a command to a file name. 
I try the following within the powershell shell:

```
$a = (Get-Date).DayofYear 
$b = get-date -format "yy"
$date = "$b$a"
echo $date
```

This works fine.

But I'd like to have a cmd-file with the output »$date.txt«. How to proceed?

Thanks for all help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$a = (Get-Date).DayofYear 
$b = get-date -format "yy"
$date = "$b$a"
$date | out-file -FilePath "$date.txt"
```

... or depending on preference

```
$date | out-file -FilePath ($date + ".txt")
```

As per your comments, you can do this from CMD like so:

```
powershell.exe "((Get-Date).DayofYear).ToString() + (get-date -format 'yy').ToString()| % {$_ |Out-File ($_ + '.txt')}"
```

Comment: Many thanks, works well except for the unexpected space between $a and $b in the filename. How to prevent this?

Comment: Sorry for bother, also I'd like to have the possibility to use this scipt inside a CMD file. How to call the powershell for all lines of  the script?

Comment: There shouldn't be a space in the filename (I'm running the script here and there aren't any spaces). If it's an issue you could always try $date = "$b$a".Replace(' ','').

Regarding your second question, please log a new question and I'll answer it.

Comment: I can see that this is your first post, from memory I think you're only allowed one question in your first hour? Anyway.. here's a freebie: (from CMD)
powershell.exe "((Get-Date).DayofYear).ToString() + (get-date -format 'yy').ToString()| % {$_ |Out-File ($_ + '.txt')}"